# What is the meaning of the Michael words: "What did you stuff for her? Mr. Johnson?"

Tags: meaning

In ***[The Lost Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Boys)***, Grandpa leaving the house & Michael say this words to him:

> Grandpa: Just going to drop by some of my handiwork to the Widow
>   Johnson.
>
> Michael: **What did you stuff for her? Mr. Johnson?**
>
> Grandpa: Yeah, well, I'll see you two guys later.
>
> Sam: That wasn't funny, Mike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, [this website](http://lostboys.wikia.com/wiki/Grandpa) says that Grandpa is a taxidermist.

> Taxidermy: the preserving of an animal's body via stuffing or mounting for the purpose of display or study
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxidermy)

A taxidermist stuffs dead animals to mount them such that they appear alive. Here is the definition of stuff:

> Stuff (verb) [1]: to pack or fill completely; cram
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stuff)

Is this dialogue, Grandpa is dropping off a stuffed animal at the Widow Johnson's house. Michael jokes that he stuffed her dead husband (presumably).

Here is a picture of a stuffed deer head:

[image]

Comment: I very nearly *downvoted* this, because I initially misread the cited question as *What did you stuff **her for**?* Which is a relatively uncommon variant of *What did you **stiff** her for?* (i.e. - *How much did you **charge** her?*, with the implication that it was an unjustifiably high price). The meaning you've set out is obviously correct, but I can't help thinking this is more a matter of *knowing the context* than of *understanding English*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I assumed this meaning when I saw it, but it did sound weird. I first had to research the movie - once I figured out he was a taxidermist, it was easy sailing :)